# CreateJS not updating dynamic textbox every second HTML 5 Canvas in animate

Tags: javascript, flash, jquery-animate, adobe, createjs

In the code below I am running a simple timer script that basically counts down from 30 seconds to 0. What I want to do is get the current second to display on the stage.

```
this.stop();

//COUNTDOWN TIMER
var minute = 0;
var second = 30;

var clock = setInterval(function() {
    second = second -1;
    if(minute == 0 && second == 0){
        clearInterval(clock)
    }

//If the seconds are less than 10, add a 0
if(second < 10){
    console.log("0"+minute+":0"+second+"");
}else{
    //Normal
    console.log("0"+minute+":"+second+"");
}

this.text = second;
this.myTimer1.myTimer2.text = second;

}, 1000);
```

However, while the countdown work and functions as expected, I constantly get the error message that `myTimer2` is not defined. I'm really struggling to find an answer to this.

`myTimer1` is the instance name of a movie clip and `myTimer2` is the instance name of a dynamic textbox within the movie clip

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure there is a `myTimer2` child (and variable) defined in `myTimer1`? Any chance you can post the lib js? What is `this` inside the interval? There is a pretty good chance the function is getting called in the global scope, so `this` will be `Window`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing this error: `Cannot read property 'myTimer2' of undefined`, then this is just a scope issue.

If you pass a function as an argument to `setInterval`, it gets called in the global scope. Any variables defined in the same scope (second, minute, etc) will still be available, but `this` becomes global.

There are a few ways to resolve the function scope:

---

A common (and easy) workaround is just to define an alias to `this` in the local scope. The function is still called in the global scope, but you now have a reference to the scope you want to reference. Typically you will see code examples with a `_this` or `that` variable:

```
var _this = this;
setTimeout(function() {
  _this.doSomething(); //
}, duration);
```

Another approach is to bind the method. This is not supported in some older browsers (there are plenty of polyfills for that), but if you are using CreateJS, then old browser support is not really a concern.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  this.doSomething();
}.bind(this), duration);
```

Hope that helps. There are [plenty of articles on scope in JavaScript](https://www.google.ca/search?q=javascript%20scope&oq=javascript%20scope) if you want to learn more.